# JUnit Test failing only on Jenkins with NPE

Tags: java, jenkins, junit

I have a JUnit test which runs ok on local environment and even on some Jenkins pipelines, but on a certain pipeline fails(let's call it develop). Furthermore, if i recreate a jenkins pipeline from the same git branch, the test will pass.
If i delete the failing pipeline and i create a new one with a different name(on which the test is passing), but i rename it back to develop(the failing one), it starts to fail again.

I imagine this is somehow related to Jenkins since it is only occurring on certain pipelines, but has somebody encountered this before?